# Proving normal distribution is a probability measure/ Sigma additivity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let 
$$P_X(B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\int_B \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma)^2}\,\lambda(dx)$$

$B$ borel and with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ parameters. Prove that $P_X$ is a probability measure.

The 3 steps are straight forward but I don't know how to prove sigma additivity

1. $P_X$ is defined on a Sigma algebra.
2. $$\int_\emptyset \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma)^2}\,\lambda(dx) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_\emptyset e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma)^2}\,\lambda(dx) \leq \lambda(\emptyset)=0$$
3. $P_X(\mathbb{R})=1.$ I know how to show this with the variable transformation.
4. How to show Sigma additivity?

Comment: Hi  - would have thought you could use the Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT) for integrals defined on suitably specified indicators reflecting the countable union over which you need to calculate the integral. I.e. your target countable union is the limit of an increasing set of finite disjoint unions whose integrals (which are partial sums over the finite disjoint partial unions) will tend to the required limit by MCT. Sorry all in words as tied up :) Hope not too cryptic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_1,B_2,\dots$ be disjoint Borel measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Let us abbreviate the integrand with $f$ which is a nonnegative and measurable function (that satisfies $\int f(x)\lambda(dx)=1$).

By definition:

$$P_X(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n)=\int1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n}(x)f(x)\lambda(dx)$$

Now observe that $1_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n}(x)f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k(x)$ where $f_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^k1_{B_n}(x)f(x)$.

This with $0\leq f_1\leq f_2\leq\cdots$ so applying MCS we find $$P_X(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int f_k(x)\lambda(dx)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\int1_{B_n}(x)f(x)\lambda(dx)$$$$=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^kP_X(B_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_X(B_n)$$

---

**edit**: smart alternative using that $\mathbb P$ denotes a (probability) measure.

Let $B_1,B_2,\dots$ be disjoint Borel measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Then the sets $\{X\in B_1\},\{X\in B_2\},\cdots$ are disjoint measurable sets and since $\mathbb P$ denotes a (probability) measure we conclude:$$P_X(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n)=\mathbb P(X\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n)=\mathbb P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X\in B_n\})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(X\in B_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_X(B_n)$$

Comment: I added a more elegant solution. It is a good thing to be equipped with both.

Comment: It didn't cross my mind to use the image measure and ignore the integral.